# how to work with new controller in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, url

I am new to Symfony 3. I have successfully installed the framework but now I want to make a new controller, namely 'ToDoController' and want to run a function in it.

This is the Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ToDoController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/todos")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "hello world";

    }
}
```

Now when I type the following URL in the browser, it gives me 404 Not found error.

> http://localhost/todolist/todos

This is the screenshot of the broweser

[image]

This is the routing.yml file in the config folder

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

I get the following page when I type the following URL in the broweser

> http://localhost/todolist/

[image]

I just want to print hello world to check if my controller is working. Please Help.

Comment: Where does `/todolist` come from? This path isn't defined at the action nor for the controller. The route `localhost/todos` should work as far as i can see.

Comment: have you added the controller to the routing.yml.  app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation

Comment: todolist is my project name. I mean the name of the project folder in my root directory.

Comment: If you don't prefix your routes, the project name doesn't matter (if i didn't missed something here). Did you try `localhost/todolist` ? Is the project defined in your local webserver so can reach the project over localhost?

Comment: I have edited the question. please check. yes I have tried localhost/todolist and gives me the page in the screenshot 2.

Comment: have you check if the route exists thanks to this command : `php bin/console debug:router`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your Apache to have an application on separate host.

[See documentation how to do it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

What you did you just copied it into a folder `todolist` in your apache directory root. But you **must** have it on a separate host, and document root of this host must be `web` folder (though it may have another name and may be moved).

So either set up a virtual host, or make `localhost` to have **only** Symfony app. Another solution - do not use Apache, use build-in web-server (`./bin/console server:run`)